# How to Change image color dynamically in android?

Tags: android

I am doing such type of project ,In my project change **Image color dynamically**.

*I have a one black shape color image ,when user click on this image change image color dynamically green.*

[image]

Googling and other document follow but I am not solve my problem .

Please help me , is there any method or document to follow solve my problem ,

Comment: I have only one single black color shape image .dynamically color change that image.

Comment: Try,to understand already discussed in stack overflow post's and find the links below: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264706/how-to-replace-color-of-an-image http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23763/colorizing-images-in-java and below links are external find this, http://forum.intern0t.org/java-ruby/3932-java-source-change-image-color.html http://www.javalobby.org/articles/ultimate-image/ http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/RGBImageFilter.html http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/

Comment: I solve my issue using http://www.41post.com/4396/programming/android-bitmap-to-integer-array

Comment: Your solution is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27384651/4632372). Hope it solves your issue.

Comment: Please have a look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27384651/4632372). I hope it helps. Thank You

Answer (score 58):

Here's how I do this: It's pulling the color from a resource xml file.

```
<resources>
<color name="new_color">#FFAAAAAA</color>
</resources>
```

In your activity .java file:

```
import android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode;

Resources res = context.getResources();
final ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageId);
final int newColor = res.getColor(R.color.new_color);
image.setColorFilter(newColor, Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

To clear it call:

```
image.setColorFilter(null);
```

Comment: thank you for replying ,i am try code but not solve my problem ,this code change whole image color not image shape color

Comment: Try a diffferent Mode and it will work for your example:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode.html

Comment: I am try different mode ,this was change image color not image shape color .

Comment: Yea, maybe OVERLAY, SATURATE, SCREEN. If you can use an alpha mask on the white part and use a white background in the parent view, that might work as well.

Comment: try this mode but i am not able to change image shape color.

Comment: res.getColor() is now depreciated. This worked instead though: ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.my_color)

Comment: This is better than `android:tint` because it's more general.  `android:tint` assumes `PorterDuff.Mode#SRC_ATOP` according to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView#setColorFilter(int)

Answer (score 27):

Set **android:tint** attribute of image/image button to the **color** you need.

```
android:tint="@android:color/black"
```

Optionally you can set **android:tintMode** attribute.

Answer (score 16):

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_person_black_48dp);

imageView.setColorFilter(imageView.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.desired_color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Answer (score 11):

Create resource in drawable folder like

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/rect"
            android:tint="@color/red"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

`android:tint="@color/red"` does it.

Comment: I have tested, it is working on api level 29 but 19.

Answer (score 3):

In XML use src not background tag in ImageView.
In java code-

```
import android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode;
final Context context=this;

        home1=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.home1);
 Resources res = context1.getResources();
        final int newColor = res.getColor(android.R.color.black);
        home1.setColorFilter(newColor, Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your OnDraw, just before you draw your square.

```
if (userclicked){
paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
} else {
paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
}
```

Of course that is if you are drawing it with canvas.drawRect(x0,y0,x1,y1,paint) which you would if you were drawing a simple shape like that.

Comment: sorry this is not my problem ,i have a black color shape image and that image color change dynamically.