# Changing image color takes too much time in android

Tags: android

I am trying to change image color dynamically in android .but it takes to much time .

Below function is used for changing color.

```
  public void greenColor(ImageView imageView,String fileName){
                System.out.println("in green color method");

             //initialize the Bitmap Object  

              Bitmap  bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileName);
               //  Bitmap bmp = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();  
                //Guarantees that the image is decoded in the ARGB8888 format  
                bmp = bmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);  



                //Initialize the intArray with the same size as the number of pixels on the image  
                int[] intArray  = new int[bmp.getWidth()*bmp.getHeight()];  

                //copy pixel data from the Bitmap into the 'intArray' array  
                bmp.getPixels(intArray, 0, bmp.getWidth(), 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight());  



                //replace the red pixels with yellow ones  
                try{
                    for (int i=0; i < intArray.length; i++)  
                    {  
                        //System.out.println("pixel value :"+intArray[i]);
                        //intArray[i] =  0xFFFF0000;  

                        if(intArray[i] == Color.WHITE)  
                        {  

                           System.out.println("color white ");
                        } else{
                            System.out.println(intArray[i]);
                            intArray[i]=Color.GREEN;
                        }
                    }  
                }catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println("pixel error "+e);
                }


                //Initialize the bitmap, with the replaced color  
                bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(intArray, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);  

                //Draw the bitmap with the replaced color  
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);  
               //----end color

        }
```

I've tried so much and did google search, but i am unable to solve my problem ,

Is there any technique to reduce image color change  time in android?

Please help me ...

Comment: Have you read this article ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14251896/change-image-color-take-too-mach-time-in-android

Comment: above link my own question .

Comment: Sorry,wrong link.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309629/how-to-change-colors-of-a-drawable-in-android

Comment: i was see your posted link,your link is not usefull for me, i am doing such type of task http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208367/how-to-change-image-color-dynamically-in-android/14208530#comment19703813_14208530

Comment: Please, see if you can find your solution here https://github.com/jrvansuita/IconHandler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your case its taking time as you are converting the image into 2d array and checking at every index.

So if image if 2000*2000 size, just imagine how much you are processing.
If you want to change the alfa or  tint then you should use the Bitmap APIs instead of doing it manually.