# How to apply an layer (color) to a image?

Tags: android, image-processing, imageview

I'm getting a map from google maps static service. I want to apply a layer of a color (with opacity to view the background) to change the result.

Original:

[image: Original Map]

Photoshoped image:

[image: Photoshoped Image]

I want to know if there is a way to do this programmatically. I send the map to a imageview, so I want to apply this effect before it is loaded.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: see LayerDrawable class

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14208530/2649012

Answer (score 1):

You can try :
`imageView.getDrawable().setColorFilter(COLORCODE, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY );`

Comment: It shows me a blank screen when I call it with a color of my colors.xml