# How do I create a circle via a drawable from Java (not Xml)?

Tags: android, android-drawable

I want to create a drawable that contains a circle with a background color that comes from an external file. As such I unfortunately can't simply load the drawable from an Xml file but have to create it dynamically in Java.
How do I create my circle directly in Java?

Comment: You can create your custom view by extending view class

Comment: You can create it by using ShapeDrawable

Comment: Why there is need to create dynamically, We can programatically the change the color of of image inside imageView and change imageview background . To change image color refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208367/how-to-change-image-color-dynamically-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a nonhacky way to create an oval shaped drawable:

```
    GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
    int fillColor = Color.parseColor("FF0000");
    gd.setColor(fillColor);
    int strokeWidth = 2; // px not dp
    int strokeColor = Color.parseColor("#000000");
    gd.setStroke(strokeWidth, strokeColor);
    gd.setShape(GradientDrawable.OVAL);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ShapeDrawables:

```
ShapeDrawable shapeDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
shapeDrawable.setIntrinsicHeight(height);
shapeDrawable.setIntrinsicWidth(width);
```

For circle, just use the same height and width.