# BufferedImage Color Channel Mask

Tags: java, image, colors, bufferedimage, mask

I have found this code on JavaDoc, but I can't seem to understand it.

```
output.setRGB(x, y, (image.getRGB(x, y) & 0xff00ff00)
                    | ((image.getRGB(x, y) & 0xff0000) >> 16)
                    | ((image.getRGB(x, y) & 0xff) << 16));
```

All I know that this code turns blue color to red in a BufferedImage.
but what if I want to replace blue with white or some other color and vice-versa?

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: In which class you saw these javadocs?

Comment: "I want to replace blue with white" white color it is combination of blue red and green you can replace blue with white

Comment: @ShreyosAdikari I got it from here: [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/RGBImageFilter.html) and here [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264706/how-to-replace-color-of-an-image)

Comment: @AlekseiBulgak I've been able to turn it to very light blue, but unfortunately not white

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I work with color I use different idea:

```
    BufferedImage image = //create Buffered image
    int rgb = image.getRGB(x,y);   //get Rgb color value
    Color color = new Color(rgb);  // create color with this value
    Color resultColor = new Color(color.getRed(), color.getBlue(), color.getGreen()); //create new color change blue and green colors values
    image.setRGB(x,y,resultColor.getRGB());   //set color
```

I think this idea is easier to understand.

if you want to get white color use this :

```
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage();
    Color color = new Color(255,255,255);
    image.setRGB(x,y,color.getRGB());
```

Comment: maybe I should have included in the question imagine that I have other objects in the image with different colors(e.g. Black), using this method would turn everything into white.

Answer (score 2):

Colors are stored like this, in hexadecimal:

```
RRGGBBAA
```

Red, green, blue, alpha. Now let's take a look at one of the lines:

```
(image.getRGB(x, y) & 0xff0000) >> 16
```

`image.getRGB(x, y)` would return an `RRGGBBAA` value, and this line is *bitmasking* it with `0xff0000`. Here is a visual:

```
RRGGBBAA
&
00FF0000
=
00GG0000
```

Therefore, it transforms the `RRGGBBAA` value into `GG0000`.

Then, there is a *bitshift* 16 **binary** bits to the right. Java can't shift bits in hexadecimal, but we are visualizing the colors in hexadecimal right now. Therefore, we must convert the 16 binary shifts into 4 hex shifts, because hexadecimal is base-16. Binary is base-2, and `2^4` is 16, the base of hexadecimal.

Therefore, you must shift right 4 bits. This would turn `GG0000` into `GG`, since the bits are being shifted 4 places to the right.

Therefore, we now have the value for the amount of green in our color.

You can apply similar logic to the other lines to see how they work.

Comment: Could you please show me an example, because all I get is bright yellow, but not white!